# Origin of anisotropic interaction in magnetic Hamiltonian in the absence of SOC

Tags: quantum-mechanics, condensed-matter, symmetry, spin-models, spin-orbit

The general second-order interactions between two spins can be decomposed into three parts: isotropic Heisenberg interaction, antisymmetric DMI and anisotropic $\Gamma$ interaction.
\begin{equation}
\mathcal{H} = \sum_{ij}J_{ij}\mathcal{S}_i\cdot\mathcal{S}_j + d_{ij}\cdot\left(\mathcal{S}_i\times\mathcal{S}_j\right) + \mathcal{S}_i\Gamma_{ij}\mathcal{S}_j
\end{equation}

My interpretation is that both two non-Heisenberg interactions originate from the spin-orbit coupling (SOC), because, in the absence of SOC, the Hamiltonian should be invariant under any global spin rotation but they are not. This result can also be justified by the superexchange microscopic mechanism [T. Moriya, “Anisotropic superexchange interaction and weak ferromagnetism,” Physical Review 120, 91 (1960)].

Nevertheless, when one computes magnetic interactions based on the Green’s function method with the local rigid spin rotation treated as a perturbation [https://arxiv.org/pdf/2009.01910.pdf], the anisotropic $\Gamma$ interaction doesn't vanish in the absence of SOC. In other words, this term does not entirely originate from SOC.

I can not find out why there is such a contradiction. **So here's my question: What's the origin of the anisotropic $\Gamma$ interaction? Why can it show up in the magnetic Hamiltonian when SOC is absent?**